# crumbs navigation - get path clicking on a crumb

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a crumb navigation and need the common way to get the path by clicking on a crumb.

For example, if clicked element is `GOLD SUN`.
Then **path** should be `HOME/BLUE SKY/GOLD SUN`.

If clicked element is `BLUE SKY` - `path` should be `HOME/BLUE SKY`

How to do that?

```js
$('.crumb').click(function()
{
    var path = /* text of all previous `crumb` + text of clicked one - divided by `/`*/;
    console.log(path);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='crumb'>HOME</div>
<div class='crumb'>BLUE SKY</div>
<div class='crumb'>GOLD SUN</div>
<div class='crumb'>SILVER MORNING</div>
<div class='crumb'>DEEP SEA</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.crumb').click(e => {
  //find all the crumbs prior to the one clicked, and add the one clicked
  var path = $(e.target).prevAll('.crumb').add(e.target);
  //get all the text of the paths, and join them by slash
  var joinedPath = path.map((index, element) => element.innerText).get().join('/');
  
  console.log(joinedPath);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='crumb'>HOME</div>
<div class='crumb'>BLUE SKY</div>
<div class='crumb'>GOLD SUN</div>
<div class='crumb'>SILVER MORNING</div>
<div class='crumb'>DEEP SEA</div>
```